# How to merge typedefs spread across multiple lines to single line?

Tags: python, bash

I want to merge `typedef`s spread across multiple lines into a single line each using either a bash command or python. Since I am totally new to scripting, I need your help.

Below is the sample input and expected output.

input:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

#define MIN_LEN 10
#define MAX_LEN 100

typedef list<int> IntList;

typedef 
map<int, string>
Names;

typedef Record
{
    int id;
    string name;
} MyRecord;

void putname(int a, string name)
{
    // do something...
}
```

output:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

#define MIN_LEN 10
#define MAX_LEN 100

typedef list<int> IntList;

typedef map<int, string> Names;

typedef Record { int id;  string name; } MyRecord;

void putname(int a, string name)
{
    // do something...
}
```

Comment: What does a bash script or Python have to do with this? Are you talking about *parsing C++* and reformatting it based on that?

Comment: @Jason This has nothing to do with C++, it's text editing of a file that happens to be C++ source code.

Comment: @BenjaminW.- Oh sorry, my bad. Thanks for the correcting it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with sed, but it's a little convoluted.

```
/^typedef/ {    # If a line starts with 'typedef'
    /;$/! {     # If the line does not end with ';'
        :loop   # Label to branch to
        N       # Append next line to pattern space
        /;$/ {                      # If the pattern space ends with ';'
            /{[^}]*}\|^[^{]*$/ {    # If matching braces or no braces at all
                s/\n/ /g            # Replace all newlines with spaces
                s/  */ /g           # Replace multiple spaces with single spaces
                b                   # Branch to end of cycle
            }
        }
        b loop  # Branch to label
    }
}
```

The first case is simple:

```
typedef 
map<int, string>
Names;
```

This could be solved by just appending the next line until we find `;`, then replacing newlines with spaces, done.

Braces containing more semicolons make it more difficult, though: if a line ends with a semicolon, the statement is only finished if we've already seen a matching pair of braces, or no braces at all (which is the first case).

Storing the script (maybe without the comments, some seds don't like them) in `sedscr`, the result for the input file looks as follows:

```
$ sed -f sedscr infile
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

#define MIN_LEN 10
#define MAX_LEN 100

typedef list<int> IntList;

typedef map<int, string> Names;

typedef Record { int id; string name; } MyRecord;

void putname(int a, string name)
{
    // do something...
}
```

This *can* be written as a one-liner, but it probably shouldn't be:

```
sed '/^typedef/{/;$/!{:a;N;/;$/{/{[^}]*}\|^[^{]*$/{s/\n/ /g;s/  */ /g;b}};ba}}' infile
```

This works for GNU sed; BSD sed might require more semicolons, especially before closing braces.